# How to Connect knative-eventing to RabbitMQ External Source

Tags: rabbitmq, knative, knative-eventing

I am trying to connect Knative with an existing RabbitMQ queue outside the Kubernetes cluster, but after testing and looking at the documentation I am not sure this can be done, does anyone know how to use Knative-eventing with an external RabbitMQ as a message source ?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

As listed in [the Knative Eventing sources catalog](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/sources/#knative-sources), there is a RabbitMQ source being developed and maintained by the community (largely contributors from VMware and the RabbitMQ team).

Documentation and install instructions are [here](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/eventing-rabbitmq/blob/main/docs/source/README.md); in the case of bugs, please report them in the associated repo.

Comment: Hi!
But in the documentation you give me it says: 

"Before we can create the Knative Eventing Source, we first need to create a RabbitMQ Cluster:" Besides referring to the creation of a broker, it implies that it only works with RabbitMQ clusters within the Kubernetes cluster itself and I want to use one already available by passing the connection data.

Comment: Hey @Juan, The source should be able to connect to an arbitrary instance of Rabbit. Here, https://github.com/knative-sandbox/eventing-rabbitmq/blob/main/test/e2e/config/source/rabbitmq-source.yaml is the e2e example where the Source is connecting to a Rabbit Instance using connection data (the instance just happens to be instantiated using the RMQ Cluster Operator for ease of use).

Comment: Which version of Knative are you using ? The team is working towards an MVP of the integration. I created an issue to clarify the instructions here - https://github.com/knative-sandbox/eventing-rabbitmq/issues/783

Comment: Hi @sameer I replied into another answer because in this box field has a character limits

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Juan you were absolutely right about our docs, here I'll leave a PR fixing part of them while it's being reviewed and merged, and with a clear example about using external RabbitMQ instances:
https://github.com/knative-sandbox/eventing-rabbitmq/pull/786/files#diff-4fdb9e4eb3a1c9da58e4445d94aa5ce4573b5c8d005f20c41c767b07c09a2418

Hope this helps =), and thanks for the feedback!
If you find anything wrong, you can comment on the PR or leave a reply over here!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

thank you @sameer for your answer, I think I am not understanding you correctly.

After visiting the link you give me, I have launched:

`kubectl apply --filename https://github.com/knative-sandbox/eventing-rabbitmq/releases/latest/download/rabbitmq-source.yaml`

To install the rabbitmq source and generated the secret:

`kubectl create secret generic rabbitmqc-default-user -n knative-eventing --from-literal=user=root --from-file=password=/tmp/password`

And the following resource:

```
apiVersion: sources.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: RabbitmqSource
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-source
  namespace: knative-eventing
spec:
  broker: "host.external.dns:5671/"
  connectionSecret:
    name: "rabbitmqc-default-user"
  user:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: "rabbitmqc-default-user"
      key: "username"
  password:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: "rabbitmqc-default-user"
      key: "password"
  exchangeConfig:
    name: "logs"
    type: "fanout"
    durable: true
    autoDelete: false
  queueConfig:
    name: "test"
    routingKey: ""
    durable: false
    autoDelete: false
  channelConfig:
    parallelism: 10
  sink:
    ref:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      name: recorder
```

But after generating the resources I get these errors:

knative-sources/rabbitmq-controller-manager

```
│ W0524 11:45:04.108665       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1beta1.Binding: the server could not find the requested resource (get bindings.rabbitmq.com)                                                                   │
│ E0524 11:45:04.108718       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Binding: failed to list *v1beta1.Binding: the server could not find the requested resource (get bindings.rabbitmq.com)                                 │
│ W0524 11:45:04.109915       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1beta1.Queue: the server could not find the requested resource (get queues.rabbitmq.com)                                                                       │
│ E0524 11:45:04.109935       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Queue: failed to list *v1beta1.Queue: the server could not find the requested resource (get queues.rabbitmq.com)                                       │
│ W0524 11:45:04.109976       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1beta1.Exchange: the server could not find the requested resource (get exchanges.rabbitmq.com)                                                                 │
│ E0524 11:45:04.109985       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Exchange: failed to list *v1beta1.Exchange: the server could not find the requested resource (get exchanges.rabbitmq.com)                              │
│ W0524 11:45:05.253806       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1beta1.Exchange: the server could not find the requested resource (get exchanges.rabbitmq.com)                                                                 │
│ E0524 11:45:05.254035       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.Exchange: failed to list *v1beta1.Exchange: the server could not find the requested resource (get exchanges.rabbitmq.com)                              │
│ W0524 11:45:05.443628       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1beta1.Queue: the server could not find the requested resource (get queues.rabbitmq.com)
```

The truth is that I have searched and searched and I have not found information on how to connect it to an external RabbitMQ to Kubernetes, maybe I am not understanding the documentation well.

Comment: You need to install the https://github.com/rabbitmq/messaging-topology-operator

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that xxx.rabbitmq.com CRD is not installed in the current k8s cluster.

│ W0524 11:45:04.109915       1 reflector.go:324] k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: failed to list *v1beta1.Queue: the server could not find the requested resource (get queues.rabbitmq.com)                                                                       │

You need to install the RabbitQA messaging-topology-operator in order to add the missing CRDS

as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/eventing-rabbitmq/blob/main/docs/source/README.md):

> Note: An external RabbitMQ instance can be used, but if you want to
> use the Source without predeclared resources (specifically the
> Exchange and Queue), the RabbitMQ Message Topology Operator needs to
> be installed in the same Kubernetes Cluster as the Source.

follow this command :

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/rabbitmq/messaging-topology-operator/releases/latest/download/messaging-topology-operator-with-certmanager.yaml
```